# JAVA - array error with string args[0]

Tags: java

/* Need help. There is an error with client class Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Client.main(Client.java:14)
I emphasized the line.

**Driver d1 = new Driver(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Double.parseDouble(args[3]));**

I could not figure out what went wrong. */

/* Driver class */

```
public class Driver {

    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private int licenseNo;
    private double yr;
    private static int id=0; 

    public Driver() {

        this.lastName = "No Name";
        this.age = 16;
        this.licenseNo = 11111;
        this.yr = 0.5;
        id++;
    }

    public Driver(String lastName, int age, int licenseNo, double yr) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.licenseNo = licenseNo;
        this.yr = yr;
        id++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Driver other = (Driver) obj;
        if (lastName.equals(other.lastName) && licenseNo==other.licenseNo)
            return true;
        else  
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The name of the Driver is:" + lastName + ", The age is:" + age + ", The license no is:" + licenseNo + ", Duration of driving:" + yr ;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getLicenseNo() {
        return licenseNo;
    }
    public void setLicenseNo(int licenseNo) {
        this.licenseNo = licenseNo;
    }
    public double getYr() {
        return yr;
    }
    public void setYr(double yr) {
        this.yr = yr;
    }
}
```

/* Client class */

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static int licenseFee(Driver dr){

        double fee=((dr.getAge()*dr.getLicenseNo())/100000)+50;
        if(fee>100)
            return 100;
        else
            return (int)fee;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Driver d1 = new Driver(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Double.parseDouble(args[3]));
        System.out.println(d1);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter driver's last name:");
        String temp1 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter age:");
        int temp2=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter license:");
        int temp3=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Years:");
        double temp4=sc.nextDouble();

        Driver d2= new Driver(temp1, temp2, temp3,temp4);
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println("License fee:"+licenseFee(d1));
        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println("License fee:"+licenseFee(d2));
        if(d1.equals(d2))
            System.out.println("Command line object is equal to keyboard object");
        else
            System.out.println("Command line object is NOT equal to keyboard object");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing in 4 arguments?

Comment: How exactly are you giving the arguments?

Comment: Yes. Pretty sure. args[0] is the string last name.

Comment: The output is supposed to be like this 
The name of the Driver is:ali, The age is:12, The license no is:12, Duration of driving:12.0
Enter driver's last name:
sunny
Enter age:
32
Enter license:
55555
Enter Years:
32.9
The name of the Driver is:ali, The age is:12, The license no is:12, Duration of driving:12.0
License fee:50
The name of the Driver is:sunny, The age is:32, The license no is:55555, Duration of driving:32.9
License fee:67
Command line object is NOT equal to keyboard object

Comment: You should be running the program with a command similar to `java Client lastName age license years`. For example `java Client sunny 32 55555 32.9`

Comment: @MisterMystery You are right. I tried to run on eclipse, no such thing. It is good using cmd.

Comment: You can add command line arguments to your Eclipse project [like so](https://www.concretepage.com/ide/eclipse/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-java-program-in-eclipse)

Comment: To format source code blocks properly, select the source code block and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but is very important that you validate all the params that you receive.

Try this in your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args == null || args.length <4){
        System.out.println("All params are required. lastname, age, licenseNo and year");           
    }else{
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Driver d1 = new Driver(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Double.parseDouble(args[3]));
        System.out.println(d1);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter driver's last name:");
        String temp1 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter age:");
        int temp2=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter license:");
        int temp3=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Years:");
        double temp4=sc.nextDouble();

        Driver d2= new Driver(temp1, temp2, temp3,temp4);
        System.out.println(d1);
        System.out.println("License fee:"+licenseFee(d1));
        System.out.println(d2);
        System.out.println("License fee:"+licenseFee(d2));
        if(d1.equals(d2))
            System.out.println("Command line object is equal to keyboard object");
        else
            System.out.println("Command line object is NOT equal to keyboard object");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

args[0], args[1], etc. are the indexes of command line arguments that you pass to main method before executing your program. It seems that you didn't pass the correct amount of arguments (at least 4) or you forgot to pass all of them.  Command line arguments are splitted with white spaces.

You might want to have a look at this link to see how to pass command line arguments through command prompt or in Eclipse or Netbeans:
http://java2career.com/2014/05/how-to-use-command-line-arguments-in.html

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\system32>cd..

C:\Windows>cd..

C:>cd Users\qle2\Downloads

C:\Users\qle2\Downloads>java Client ali 32 55555 32.5

The name of the Driver is:ali, The age is:32, The license no is:55555, Duration of driving:32.5

Enter driver's last name:
Alibaba

Enter age:
50

Enter license:
1234567

Enter Years:
12

The name of the Driver is:ali, The age is:32, The license no is:55555, Duration of driving:32.5

License fee:67
The name of the Driver is:Alibaba, The age is:50, The license no is:1234567, Duration of driving:12.0

License fee:100

Command line object is NOT equal to keyboard object